# delayed redirect user in php in a facebook app

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

i have made a facebook app, i want the user to be **redirected automatically after filling a form**
but it doesnt really redirect to user facebook home instead it will show a facebook link there on the app.

```
<?php
          print "Records added to the database";
             sleep(10);//seconds to wait..
             header("Location:http://www.facebook.com");    ?>
```

this is how i am doing facebook connect its workin,

```
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Get the user profile data you have permission to view
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($user_profile);
    echo "</pre>";
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
} else {
  die('<script>top.location.href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl().'";</script>');
}
```

Comment: you cant send any output before a header, if error checking was on you would of got an error message.

Comment: you can't do that with php . sleep as wait then header, php doesn't run on client side it does send the whole output which doesn't work, since headers already sent when you printed, and then you send header. you need to use javascript redirect after x seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried this

```
$loginUrl= "facebook.com";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
```

the put http:// in the link and it did redirect it,

```
 $loginUrl= "http://facebook.com";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
```

still couldnt find a way to do a delayed redirect, tried alot of javascripts but in facebook, it wont work i guess due to iframes. only the above statement is working without any delay

Answer (score 1):

you can't do that with php . sleep as wait after printing then redirect, php doesn't run on client side it will just send the whole output after sleeping for 10 which doesn't work and not what you want,  it already created headers when you executed print, then you added another header, the browser won't obey the second header.  and in fact you should get a warning by php that headers already sent.

what you need is a javascript redirect after xxx 
something like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> window.setTimeout(function(){window.location="http://facebook.com";},10000) </script
```

Comment: if ($db_found) {
$today = getdate(); 
$SQL = "INSERT INTO DailyData (User,Date,Score,Comment) VALUES ('$_POST[UserID]','$today[year]-$today[mon]-$today[mday]','$_POST[element_1]','$_POST[Comments]')";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

mysql_close($db_handle);
print "
<script type='text/javascript';> window.setTimeout(function(){window.location='facebook.com'},10000) </script>
Records added to the database";



}
else {
print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}
?>

Comment: well you need to have http://facebook.com,  sorry, I wrote the answer in a hurry, and didn't add http I assumed you ll replace it with different url.  I ll edit my answer, also I notice there is ; between after "text/javascript" not sure if that's a typo when you pasted or you put that in code, if so please try to remove it

Comment: edit: you need to have http in front facebook,   http was cut from the above. comment ):

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo '<fb:redirect url="'.$url.'"/>';
```

Comment: didnt work, code below ----------- if ($db_found) {
$today = getdate(); 
$SQL = "INSERT INTO DailyData (User,Date,Score,Comment) VALUES ('$_POST[UserID]','$today[year]-$today[mon]-$today[mday]','$_POST[element_1]','$_POST[Comments]')";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

mysql_close($db_handle);
/*print "
<script type='text/javascript';> window.setTimeout(function(){window.location='facebook.com'},10000) </script>
Records added to the database";*/
echo "Records Added";
$url ="facebook.com";
echo '<fb:redirect url="'.$url.'"/>';


}
else {
print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}
?>